# loading mangeto in milli seconds

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

Some magento websites load in milli seconds. 
Mine takes 4 seconds, I have enables cache but still it takes so long.
How do these other websites load so quick?
I have done all the setting here

http://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/

My server has 32GB ram and 12 cores

Answer (score 0):

You are never going to get Magento to load in milli seconds whatever your hardware setup without using a full page cache solution or Varnish to cache and then serve full page HTML.

Comment: I have added opcache but still it loads in 4 seconds.
I meant server response time.

Comment: I'm not talking about an opcode cache, I'm talking about full page cache.  This stores the generated full page HTML for each request so the next time a request comes in for the same content the server doesn't have to generate all of the HTML for that page again, it just serves the cached content.  This massively boosts performance giving hugely decreased TTFB.

Comment: can you give me one example of such cache?
"a full page cache solution or Varnish to cache and then serve full page HTML."
So I need to use Varnish and some thing else?
Or only opcache and Varnish?

Comment: `You are never going to get Magento to load in milli seconds` Of course you can. A standard demo store with sample data and no additional caches (application or server side) will load in <400ms on a category page. You don't need a FPC or Varnish to make a site quick - neither are relevant as far as performance is concerned. Caches reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content, they do not make anything faster.

Comment: Can some one just tell me what caches to use thats all im asking. 
I have opcache and magento cache installed. 
what else will "Caches reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content"

Comment: 400ms is nearly half a second.  I admit that the OP didn't specify how many milliseconds was 'good', but in my opinion 400ms is more closely equated to seconds than a few milliseconds.  With FPC or Varnish you are looking at well under 100ms, often under 50ms.  On the very modest setup of our own store we see <50ms HTML generation times with FPC - this I think is more the kind of times the OP is looking for - impossible without FPC.

Comment: @nikhilcarvalho there are many FPC solutions available on magento connect, with ours, [Evolved Caching](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/evolved-caching.html), being one (which we consider to be one of the fastest). Bear in mind FPC isn't a magic bullet, you should ensure store performance is acceptable without it as areas such as the cart and checkout are never going to be cached and a slow checkout = lost sales. Also look at Varnish (just do a search, loads of information out there).  With these solutions you will get performance it's impossible to achieve without any caching.